# Can I move documents out of Folder?

Tags: 2013, document-library, document, sharepoint-library, move

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have a Library with two PDFs in a Folder. I also have five documents within the Library that are not placed in folders. Is there a way for me to move the PDFs from within the folder to where the other documents are, or must I delete the folder and attach the PDFs as new documents?

Thanks
[image: Document Library Image]

Comment: Can you sync to the document library?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sync to the document library."

Comment: If setup by your SharePoint admin, you can sync document libraries to your OneDrive. You can then open the library in Windows Explorer and move files around at will. Click LIBRARY on the ribbon and in the Connect & export section, you should see a Sync option, it may or may not be enabled.

Comment: I see the Connect & Export. However, only the Connect to Outlook, and Export to Excel, as well as Open with Explorer are active. The  Connect to Office is inactive. So my SharePoint admin did not enable it. By the way, what is OneDrive? Is it Microsoft's Cloud?

Comment: Yes, it is a Microsoft Cloud. In that same section do you have the Open with Explorer option? This is what the the answer below is referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open this library in explorer mode (works on in IE) ==> Then cut the files from the PDF_Files folder and paste it one level up , just like in normal windows folder.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But it doesn't seem to be working. I'll try a few more times and give you details.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach, SharePoint has"Manage content and Structure" that lets you to move files/list items.

Please see reference link here http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/29/how-to-use-the-site-content-and-structure-manager-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

http://mroffice365.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-manage-content-and-structure/

Bacially in the Manage content and Structure page, you need navigate to specific folder and select files then using action menu > select Move > You have to select the target destination folder to save it.

By using this approach, you can preserve all the metadata information such as created, last modified date on the file.